# Perl long data type

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I am writing an app in Perl that requires long data type instead of integers. How can I achieve this. For example;

```
my $num = sprintf('%ld', 27823221234);

print $num;
```

The output is not a long, but an integer.

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit version of Perl?
The output of `sprintf()` is a string.  What are you really wanting to do?

Comment: Am running a 64-bit version. Am writing a xmlrpc client that requires a long type instead of integer. 
Remote Error [0]: No method matching arguments: java.lang.String,

Comment: @Gruther: how did you get an error from java.lang.String from a Perl program?  Did you choose the correct language tag?

Comment: Am running 64-bit version. It's a xmlrpc client that requires a long type and not an integer. AM passing an eleven digits cellphone number to the remote server

Remote Error [0]: No method matching arguments: java.lang.Integer

Comment: It's a client API. The server xmlrpc was written in JAVA

Comment: You need to use `RPC::XML` properly then.

Comment: If you're running a 64-bit Perl, then the problem is not in the Perl per se, but in what it is sending to the Java application.  And that is a much more difficult question to answer - not least because it will likely involve many modules and many lines of code.  You have not demonstrated the output you get from the Perl snippet; you have not demonstrated the output you want from the Perl snippet.  With a 64-bit Perl, you should not see anything different from what I show in my answer.  So, you need to work out a lot more clearly what the problem is, so that you can ask an answerable question.

Comment: Maybe my question was to be; Can I get a Java long type equivalent in Perl? ref: http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/basic_types/21integers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that illustrates some of how Perl behaves - derived from your example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $num = sprintf("%ld", 27823221234);
print "$num\n";

my $val = 27823221234;
my $str = sprintf("%ld", $val);
printf "%d = %ld = %f = %s\n", $val, $val, $val, $val;
printf "%d = %ld = %f = %s\n", $str, $str, $str, $str;
```

With a 64-bit Perl, this yields:

```
27823221234
27823221234 = 27823221234 = 27823221234.000000 = 27823221234
27823221234 = 27823221234 = 27823221234.000000 = 27823221234
```

If you really need big number (hundreds of digits), then look into the modules that support them.  For example:

- [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math%3a%3aBigInt)

Answer (score 12):

Your options are:

- use a perl compiled for 64 bits
- use [Math::Int64](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::Int64)
- use [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::BigInt)

**update:**
ah, you can also use floats instead of integers:

```
printf("%.0f", 2**50)
```

IIRC, on most current architectures, floats can represent integers up to 2**54-1 precisely.

Answer (score 1):

in your case 27823221234 is really represented as double, so when you try to feed to to sprintf you receive -1

```
my $x = 27823221234;

my $num = sprintf('%lf', $x);

print $num, "\n";
```

yields to

```
27823221234.000000
```

if you want to do math operations with large integers, consider using Math::Bigint module.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably confused.  Perl natively supports "long"-sized integer math, but I don't think its internal representation is where your problem is.  What are you expecting your output to look like?